# How to do aspect to fill in img tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to  fill my image while maintaining aspect ratio(Aspect to fill),
This is how it currently looks(background color is my div)
[image]

this is my CSS

```
.img_model{
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}
.square img.wide {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.square img.tall {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

js code

```
$('.img_model').loadImages({
  imgLoadedClb: function(){},
  allLoadedClb: function(){},
  imgErrorClb:  function(){},
  noImgClb:     function(){},
  dataAttr:     'src'
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $('.square').find('img').each(function(){
  var imgClass = (this.width/this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
 })
});
```

this is how I created div in java script

```
while(i<=22)
    {
        if(!document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i))
        {
            var ele = document.createElement("div");
            ele.setAttribute("id","timedrpact"+i);
            ele.setAttribute("class","col-sm-6 col-md-4 box  portfolio-item square");
            ele.setAttribute("style","background-color:"+arr[i]);
            output.appendChild(ele);

            var ele = document.createElement("a");
            ele.setAttribute("id","a"+i);
            ele.setAttribute("class","a_square");
             ele.setAttribute("href","www.google.com");
            ele.setAttribute("target","_self");
            ele.setAttribute("style","text-decorartion:none");
            document.getElementById("timedrpact"+i).appendChild(ele);

            var ele = document.createElement("img");
            ele.setAttribute("id","img"+i);
            ele.setAttribute("class","img_model");
            ele.setAttribute("style","width:100%;height:auto;");
            ele.setAttribute("src","http://luteciamodels.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3_model_77997_3840x2160.jpg");
            document.getElementById("a"+i).appendChild(ele);
        }
        i++;


    }
```

am expecting output like   this first image in green circle....
Pls help me
[image]

Comment: if you are using `object-fit` why not just use `object-fit: cover` to get the image to fill the container?

Comment: @MarkM make it as answer so i can accept, its working nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object-fit: cover` will fill the container without distorting the image.

Answer (score 0):

object-fit is not supported on any version of IE, what you want to do this with is CSS and have the image be the background of the div and set the background-size to cover.

This is a good tutorial on how to do this and get the aspect ratios you want to use:
http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Using those CSS properties will get you support on IE all the way down to v8.

Answer (score 0):

easy done if you set a callback when image is loaded:

```
function updateImage(domimage,src){
    var tempImg = new Image();
    tempImg.onload = function(){
        var ratio = this.width/this.height;
        domimage.setAttribute("class", ratio < 1 ? "wide" : "tall");
    }
    tempImg.src = src
}
```

use as:

```
        var ele = document.createElement("img");
        ele.setAttribute("id","img"+i);
        ele.setAttribute("class","img_model");
        ele.setAttribute("style","width:100%;height:auto;");
        var imagesrc = "http://xxx.jpg";
        ele.setAttribute("src",imagesrc);
        document.getElementById("a"+i).appendChild(ele);
        updateImage(ele,imagesrc)
```

not tested. i forgot how to use vanilla selector. use jquery. really more simple and clean